# Insert column from other table / merge tables

Tags: mariadb

This would be similar to using a spreadsheet application. I have a table `t1`:

```
date       | time     | windspd | winddir
-----------+----------+---------+--------
2014-02-16 | 00:00:00 |       0 |    NULL
2014-02-16 | 00:00:10 |       0 |    NULL
2014-02-16 | 00:00:20 |       0 |    NULL
2014-02-16 | 00:00:30 |       0 |    NULL
2014-02-16 | 00:00:40 |       0 |    NULL
2014-02-16 | 00:00:50 |       0 |    NULL
2014-02-16 | 00:01:00 |       0 |    NULL
2014-02-16 | 00:01:10 |       0 |    NULL
2014-02-16 | 00:01:20 |       0 |    NULL
2014-02-16 | 00:01:30 |       0 |    NULL
```

And a table `t2`:

```
date       | time     | windspd | winddir
-----------+----------+---------+--------
2014-02-16 | 00:00:00 |    NULL |       0
2014-02-16 | 00:00:10 |    NULL |       0
2014-02-16 | 00:00:20 |    NULL |       0
2014-02-16 | 00:00:30 |    NULL |       0
2014-02-16 | 00:00:40 |    NULL |       0
2014-02-16 | 00:00:50 |    NULL |       0
2014-02-16 | 00:01:00 |    NULL |       0
2014-02-16 | 00:01:10 |    NULL |       0
2014-02-16 | 00:01:20 |    NULL |       0
2014-02-16 | 00:01:30 |    NULL |       0
```

I want to merge these tables so each row has a non-null value for `windspd` and `winddir`. The merged table would look like the following:

```
date       | time     | windspd | winddir
-----------+----------+---------+--------
2014-02-16 | 00:00:00 |       0 |       0
2014-02-16 | 00:00:10 |       0 |       0
2014-02-16 | 00:00:20 |       0 |       0
2014-02-16 | 00:00:30 |       0 |       0
2014-02-16 | 00:00:40 |       0 |       0
2014-02-16 | 00:00:50 |       0 |       0
2014-02-16 | 00:01:00 |       0 |       0
2014-02-16 | 00:01:10 |       0 |       0
2014-02-16 | 00:01:20 |       0 |       0
2014-02-16 | 00:01:30 |       0 |       0
```

The `date` and `time` columns are identical on both tables, so I could insert the column `t2.winddir` to `t1`, if there's a way to do that.

I know that I could use a join, but I tested on a smaller size: it takes about 25 to 30-ish seconds per row testing for date and time being equal.

Is there any faster way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If date & time are identical and work as a unique identifier in both tables:

```
SELECT 
    t1.date,
    t1.time,
    COALESCE(t1.windspeed,t2.windspeed) as windspeed,
    COALESCE(t1.winddir,t2.winddir) as winder
FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.date = t2.date AND t1.time = t2.time
```

This is a query for create table:

```
CREATE TABLE tblName AS

SELECT 
      t1.date,
      t1.time,
      COALESCE(t1.windspeed,t2.windspeed) as windspeed,
      COALESCE(t1.winddir,t2.winddir) as winder
FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.date = t2.date AND t1.time = t2.time
```

To work properly (fast), create combined indexes on both tables on (date, time).